# Verify receipt locally google play flutter

Tags: android, flutter, in-app-purchase, google-play-services

I would like to perform such request client side :

```
Response response = await get(Uri.parse("https://androidpublisher.googleapis.com/androidpublisher/v3/applications/com.myappname.android/purchases/products/${details.productID}/tokens/$token"));
```

But Google is asking for an OAuth token as stated in this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/rest/v3/purchases.products/get) :

> Authorization Scopes

> Requires the following OAuth scope:

> https://www.googleapis.com/auth/androidpublisher

I am aware that i should create a service account or setup an OAuth client, but i could not figure out how to link this into my app (client).

In my production app i have service side the `service_account.json` that allows me to do so but i would like to do it client side for some reasons this time (i am aware that this is not the right way to go for many reasons).

How can i link / use the service account to make a successful call client side to the `androidpublisher` url ?